# Assigning the answer of Solve to a variable

Tags: equation-solving

If I enter

```
Solve[(x-2)(x+2)==0,x]
```

then the answer comes up as

```
{{x -> 2}, {x -> -2}}
```

I want to make two variables sol1 and sol2, and sol1=2 and sol2=-2.

I don't mean I want to make sol1 and sol2 from {{x -> 2}, {x -> -2}}

I want to make them directly before anything such as {{x -> 2}, {x -> -2}} comes up.

As long as I get sol1 and sol2, I don't need such answers like {{x -> 2}, {x -> -2}}

I know it's possible because a year ago I could manage to do it after hours of trial-and-error.

But I don't remember now.

Comment: `{sol1, sol2} = x /. Solve[(x - 2) (x - 2) == 0, x]` ?

Comment: @Kuba Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Specifically this section of the "pitfalls" question: [Using the result of functions that return replacement rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users#answer-18706)